# Search for pattern in dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got a huge csv file which contains data about a bicycle being driven. 
So I got a time column in seconds and a Speed column.
I would like to check for specific pattern in the data, in order to conclude what happend on the road.

For example driving torwards a traffic light:

I got this so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('.csv', usecols = ['time', 'speed']) 
df['accelerating'] = df['speed'].diff() > 0
```

And I want something like this:

```
  df_traffic_light = df.loc[df['speed'] < 15 & accelerating == False #driving torwards the traffic light; 
    & df.loc[df['speed']< 1 #getting really slow or Standing still;
    & df.loc[df['speed']  > 5 & accelerating == True #for light switched to green and starting again
```

Expected Output:

```
         time     speed  acceleration
0   5.000         14.0          false
1   7.056         12.0          false
2   10.097         8.0          false
3   12.131         1.0          false
4   14.165         0.0          false
5   16.201         0.0          false
6   18.236         2.0          true 
7   20.267         4.0          true
```

I tried it with dataframe.rolling but didnt work out quite well. Any ideas how I solve this?

Comment: Seems you have deleted your previous post and asked exactly the same question again. Is your question (a) how to add additional boolean columns that satisfy certain conditions _you know and can explicitly describe_, or (b) how to find out the characteristics for "driving torwards the traffic light" or "getting really slow or Standing still" or "for light switched to green and starting again". Because it seems the conditions you set in your example are randomly defined and may not reflect the truth.

Comment: @ascripter yea the conditions are just an example. It is more (b) but I want to filter the whole process as a pattern. If I only filter one Argument like "getting slow" I get a lot of Output. But I just want the whole pattern together so I can conclude, that there must have been a traffic light.
Thanks for your answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not be satisfying, but as you describe the problem, it is impossible to solve. As long as you have *no* information what a certain (sub)sequence represents in reality, there is no possibility of segmenting the data into labeled classes like "driving torwards the traffic light" or whatever.

Besides manually tweaking your logic functions, visualizing data and reasoning on it,
I see 2 options from the field of machine learning:

1. **Supervised learning**: You'll need at least *some* labeled data from which an algorithm can learn what the characteristics of certain classes are. I.e. you'll need some events of which you *know* what they represent, either by experiment (let 10 different people each generate 10 times the events / classes you want to identify) or by manually assessing (sub)sequences of your data, visualizing and judging them according to your expert knowledge. The [`sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/user_guide.html) package comprises some more or less simple methods to predict the classes of the still unknown data then, i.e. [decision trees](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) or [support vector machines](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)
2. **Unsupervised learning**: You just search for characteristic subsequences, w/o a priori knowing what they represent. [`sklearn.cluster`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) has some algorithms for that. It will then also be up to you and your expert knowledge to look at the characteristics of the clusters and give them labels.

Both approaches require some effort to get into it. But I hope it points you to the right direction. If more specific questions should arise during your research that you don't find answers to, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for your Input and your thoughts on the Problem. I will try out your suggestions asap.